# Building a conda package based on R package PNG fails with error "gcc is not able to compile..."

Tags: r, gcc, conda

I would like to build a **conda** package from a R package available on the **CRAN** server. I run the following commands:

```
conda config --add channels r
conda skeleton cran png # for example
conda build r-png/ # patchelf package is installed
```

The last command leads to the following error:

```
Linking packages ...
cc1: error: /root/anaconda/envs/_build/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.5/include: Keine Berechtigung
cc1: error: /root/anaconda/envs/_build/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.5/include-fixed: Keine Berechtigung
Installation failed: gcc is not able to compile a simple 'Hello, World' program.
Error: post-link failed for: gcc-4.8.5-3
```

This error message is true for all my trials to build a **conda** package bsed on **R CRAN packages**.

Can anybody help?